# NativeScript core TextField onTextChange in model and outside model

Tags: javascript, events, nativescript

I´m using NativeScript 5.0 core and it seems that there's no method to do textChange events on textfields. My idea is something like this:

```
<TextField class="width90" text="{{ productPrize }}" editable="true" textChange="{{ onTexTextChange }}"/>
```

and in js side:

```
exports.onReSonTexTextChangecanPrize = function (args) {
  alert(test);
};
```

this sintax works fine for me in "tap" events, but i read something like there's no method for doing that o NativeScript core 5.0.

I found a method in NativeScript doc doing this stuff in module:

```
const observableModule = require("tns-core-modules/data/observable");

function HomeViewModel() {
    const viewModel = observableModule.fromObject({
        productCode: "",
        productPrize: ""
    });

    viewModel.addEventListener(observableModule.Observable.propertyChangeEvent, (args) => {
        // args is of type PropertyChangeData
        console.log("propertyChangeEvent [eventName]: ", args.eventName);
        console.log("propertyChangeEvent [propertyName]: ", args.propertyName);
        console.log("propertyChangeEvent [value]: ", args.value);
        console.log("propertyChangeEvent [oldValue]: ", args.oldValue);
        console.log("propertyChangeEvent [object]: ", args.object);
    });


    return viewModel;
}

module.exports = HomeViewModel;
```

I'm getting the logs correctly, but I don't know how to export the correspondant value to the model.

I have this code for conecting to the view:

```
const HomeViewModel = require("./home-view-model");

exports.onNavigatingTo = function(args) {
  page = args.object;
  mv = page.bindingContext = new HomeViewModel();
};
```

I wanted to know how can I do this like the example, but it will be interesting to know how could it be developed on module too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a method, but I don't know if it's a "clean" solution or if there is a better solution:

```
page.getViewById("texFieldId").addEventListener("textChange", function(args){
    console.log("text changed");
  })
```

Comment: That's the solution, property change events doesn't work from XML.

Comment: perfect, lots of thanks. that confirmation helps me a lot.